# Why was the command name `\infty` chosen?

Tags: tex-history

I had heard that a sensible scheme for naming functions and arguments should avoid somewhat arbitrary abbreviations. There are, for example, a multitude of ways to abbreviate or misspell infinity, but a single correct one that is much easier to remember than any specific abbreviation, e.g. `infnty`.

Why then do we have `\infty`? What was Knuth thinking? Am I the only one gets this wrong 50% of the time when I need it? Am I missing something about the programming style of latex?

Comment: Idle speculation not informed by any actual historical evidence: It's nice to have to type only 5 letters ("infty") rather than 8 letters ("infinity") -- fewer chances of typos, if nothing else... Abbreviating the name of the macro even further, e.g., to just 3 letters, was probably judged unwise as ambiguity might arise with respect to the math operator `\inf` ("infimum").

Comment: presumably because it is faster to type. Similar question: why is `\cong` the name for `=` with a `~` on top. `\congruence` might be a better name. You can always make your own name for the symbols you use. It is actually a good idea. In the field I wrote my thesis, `\cong` means isomorphism, so using `\newcommand\isomorph\cong` would make sense in my thesis.

Comment: several others are shortened `\sqrt`, `\pm`, `\prod`(uct), `\int`(egral) ... so `\infty` doesn't seem that out of place, but anyway I think the only person who can answer is not a member of the site so this has to be closed as "opinion-based" as no real answer possible.

Comment: Not an answer to the question but: if you don't like `\infty` why don't you defy Knuth and make a `\newcommand\infnty{\infty}`?

Comment: Actually, removing vowels (except for 1st letter) is a fairly common abbreviation technique, I think, because the brain can fill in vowels naturally when trying to decipher it.  If that still isn't short enough, then some additional consonants may also be removed (p.2 of http://www.lsbm.ac.uk/assets/pdf/Helpful-abbreviations-for-speedy-note-taking.pdf, and http://pe.usps.gov/text/pub28/28c3_027.htm).     Note:  not to be confused with "disemvowling" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disemvoweling)